# webservice sessionless-authentication like amazon s3 more strong with rsa?

Tags: security, openssl, rsa

I've implemented a webservice authentication which works pretty much the same like amazon s3.

The authentication is session-less. It works like this:

- send a `Date` HTTP Header in each request
- send a HMAC_SHA1 of secretKey+contents of date-header+some-parts-of-the-body (pseudo code: `hmac_sha1(secretKey+dateHeader+substr(body,0,100))`)
- The backend also knows the secretKey (20 char random key).
- The backend checks the request by also doing the same HMAC_SHA1 and if the value is equal, the request is "proven" and will be executed.

So. I think thats pretty much was amazon does.

But what about the idea of doing not a symmetric (HMAC_SHA1) instead doing a asymmetric encryption (RSA) of the "parts of the request"?

I would like to avoid having the secretKey on my backend. Better only place the public key on the backend side.

- Do you think this is a good idea?
- Would it make the system "stronger"?
- What's a good max size for encrypting with RSA? 1000bytes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this with RSA you will have the public key on the client-side and the private key on the server-side (a.k.a. backend). You will always end up with some secret key somewhere...

IF you are worried about security:

- list all potential risk scenrios (technical and otherwise)
- check how probable each scenario is
- check how much is "costs" if that specific scenario becomes reality
- audit your current security infrastructure

THEN go ahead and take care of the most problematic points (i.e. highest "cost" and/or "highest" probability).

Comment: Thanks. But why i need the private key on the server side? The server only create a encrypted content of the header and part of the body and than compare it with the encrypted content of the request sent from client. So. Only encryption is needed on the server side. Not?

Comment: @JonasSchnelli the client encrypts with a public key, decryptions then needs the private key... IF you never decrypt anything then you don't need the private key... BUT then you are not better off than you are now - you still have a shared secret (client and server know the public key)...

Comment: @JonasSchnelli another point: security/strength of symetric/asymetric keys differs - for example: a 3072 bit RSA is similar to AES128 according to [NIST](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-57/sp800-57-Part1-revised2_Mar08-2007.pdf) page 63.